# PHP: Expects parameter to be string array given

Tags: php

I am trying to read a csv file line by line and save its content in an array. I then parse the array using foreach to print each line.

However, when i try to send the variable(which according to me should be a string) to the deleteInstance method it prints as an array and not plain string.

I have issue sending this to Softlayer API since it throw me an error saying string expected but array given ? I am not sure what is wrong

a.csv

```
7381838
7381840
7381842
```

php

```
   <?PHP
    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php';

    function readCSV($csvFile){
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);
        return $line_of_text;
    }


    // Set path to CSV file
    $csvFile = 'a.csv';

    $csv = readCSV($csvFile);

    foreach ($csv as $value) {
        var_dump($value);
        print_r($value); 
        deleteInstance($value);

    }

    function deleteInstance($ccid){

        $apiUsername = 'xxxxx';
        $apiKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $cancelRightNow = true; //or false if you want to wait till the billing cycle ends

       $cloudComputingInstanceId = $ccid; 
        print_r($cloudComputingInstanceId);
        var_dump($cloudComputingInstanceId);

$client = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest',    $cloudComputingInstanceId, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$objectMask = new SoftLayer_ObjectMask();
$objectMask->billingItem;
$client->setObjectMask($objectMask);
$cci = $client->getObject();
$client = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Billing_Item', $cci->billingItem->id, $apiUsername, $apiKey);
$billingItem = $client->getObject();
if ($billingItem != null) {
    if ($cancelRightNow) {
        $client->cancelService();
    } else {
        $client->cancelServiceOnAnniversaryDate();
    }
}
    }


    ?>
```

[image]

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be in the code you posted. More code - especially the bits that use functionality provided by SoapClient.class.php - would help.

Comment: The error has to do with the `trim()` function. It is never used in the code  that you are showing us. We need to see the code where the function is used in order to help you. The error is quite self explanatory, though...

Comment: fgetcsv returns an array - so your readCSV is returning an array of arrays, not an array of string.

Comment: I assume youre trying to set a Parameter for his API call using one of the `$lines_of_text` which is an array parsed from the CSV. You need to show us your usage of the API.

Comment: thanks for your replies I have added the other half of the code. When i pass $cloudComputingInstanceId = "7381838"; it works fine.

Comment: Modify your code to be deleteInstance($value[0]) and everything should be hunky-dory :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your argument to `deleteInstance` is an array... It looks like this:

```
$csv = Array(
   0 => Array(0 => '7381838'),
   1 => Array (0 => '7381840'),
   2 => Array(0 => '7381842')
)
```

This is because you are parsing it as CSV which splits each line into an array based on a delimiter. This is not what you want. Instead use `file` to read each line into an array:

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    return file($csvFile);

}

$csv = readCSV('a.csv');

foreach ($csv as $value) {
    // your value is now the line of the file like '7381838'
    deleteInstance($value);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this and see what happens

```
foreach ($csv as $value) {
    $svalue = $value[0];
    var_dump($svalue);
    print_r($svalue); 
    deleteInstance($svalue);
}
```

Comment: Notice array to string conversion error on that line. I suspect it is for some reason thinking the variable is still an array.

Comment: edited, this should work if it does indeed believe it is an array