# Unable to edit while using trim in function

Tags: php, html

I am designing an application and in my modal came across a strange error where i am unable to edit the entry

Below is the modal where its showing the error lies :

```
 <?php
    include_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . "/const.php";
    include_once PHP_PATH . "/config1.php";
    include_once CONFIG_PATH.'/modal/routemgmt/route_mgmt.php';

   function sanitize($input) {
   if (is_array($input))
        return array_map('sanitize', $input);
    else
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
}

    // Sanitize all the incoming data
    $sanitized = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);
    $reason = $sanitized['reason'];

    if($reason == "insert"){
        $staffs = [];
        $stops = [];
        $name = $sanitized['rname'];
        $code = $sanitized['rcode'];
        $desc = $sanitized['rdesc'];
        $vnum = $sanitized['vnum'];
        $stf = $_POST['staff'];
        $st = isset($_POST['stops'])? $_POST['stops']: [];
        $st = [];
    //    foreach($staffs as $staff){
    //        $stf[] = array_map('sanitize', $staff);
    //    }
    //    if(isset($stops)){
    //        foreach($stops as $stop){
    //            $st[] = array_map('sanitize', $stop);
    //        }
    //    }

        $val = insertRoute($conn,$name, $code, $desc, $vnum, $stf, $stops);
        echo $val;
    }

    if($reason == "view"){
        $id = $sanitized['id'];
        $val = [];

        $val = viewRoute($conn,$id);
        echo json_encode($val);
    }

    if($reason == "edit"){
        $stf = [];
        $stp = [];
        $id = $sanitized['pkid'];
        $name = $sanitized['rname'];
        $code = $sanitized['rcode'];
        $desc = $sanitized['rdesc'];
        $vnum = $sanitized['vnum'];
        $estaffs = $_POST['estaff'];
        $estops = $_POST['estops'];
        $edel = $_POST['del'];

        foreach($estaffs as $val){
            $stf[] = array_map('sanitize', $val);
        }
        foreach($estops as $val){
            $stp[] = array_map('sanitize', $val);
        }
        $cnt = 0;$n_stp = [];
        for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($stp); $i++){
            if($stp[$i]['stat'] != "Exist"){
                $n_stp[$cnt] = $stp[$i];
                $cnt++;
            }
        }

        $val = editValues($conn,$id, $name, $code, $desc, $vnum, $stf, $n_stp, $edel);
        echo $val;
    }

    if($reason == "delRoute"){
        $id = $sanitized['id'];
        $val = delRoute($conn,$id);
        echo $val;
    }

I tried changing the function to :

    function sanitize($input) {
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
    }
```

But then it started giving me the below error

```
<b>Warning</b>:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\gurukul\demo2\controller\routemgmt\route_mgmt.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
```

As far as I can understand its passing an array instead of string in trim.
Can someone please guide me how can I resolve this ? Tried few debugging steps but didnt get succeded

Comment: Where is your `$_POST['estaff'];` and `$_POST['estops'];` Values. The error because you sent the array instead of string value.

Comment: *As far as I can understand its passing an array instead of string in trim.* No it's **you** that pass an array to trim. It's not the code doing it by itself.

Comment: The error is caused by your change to the sanitize function, put it back, then what was the original issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: Expects parameter to be string array given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178487/php-expects-parameter-to-be-string-array-given)

Comment: I don't think someone could help by looking at this code. There is no line where `sanitize` has been invoked

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Here `$stf[] = array_map('sanitize', $val);` :)

Comment: And here: `$sanitized = array_map('sanitize', $_POST);` and POST is definitely an array.

Comment: @Nawin Yeah right. I searched for `sanitize(` in browser and it gave only two results. Did not thought that it could have been passed in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

In this function you are returning array in your if statement when it should just be a string all the time.

**Replace:**

```
   function sanitize($input) {
   if (is_array($input))
        return array_map('sanitize', $input);
    else
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
}
```

**With:**

```
   function sanitize($input) {
   if (is_array($input))
        return sanitize($input);
    else
        return htmlspecialchars(trim($input));
   }
```

You need to return value as string not array. Don't mess with the `$_POST` one.

**Replace all:**

```
array_map('sanitize', $val);
```

**With:**

```
sanitize($val);
```

Comment: `return sanitize($input);`? Is that correct? Will just pass the same array to the function that line is in

Comment: Yes it is.,,,,,